# Can I simplify this Makefile involving files in subfolders?

Tags: makefile

I have, for example, the following Makefile to generate PDF files from Markdown files in subdirectories:

```
FOLDERS = f1 f2 f3
.PHONY: $(FOLDERS)

f1: f1/f1.md
    cd $@ && pandoc $(notdir $^) -o $(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,$(notdir $^))

f2: f2/f2.md
    cd $@ && pandoc $(notdir $^) -o $(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,$(notdir $^))

f3: f3/f3.md
    cd $@ && pandoc $(notdir $^) -o $(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,$(notdir $^))
```

The expected result is that `make f1` requires the existence of `f1/f1.md`, and generates the resulting PDF as `f1/f1.pdf`. The same for `f2` and `f3`. This works, but the declarations seem unnecessarily repetitive.

Is there any way to combine these three rules into one, generic rule? That is, without needing to explicitly write out all of the paths to the PDF files or Markdown files, as I may be dynamically adding subfolders and I'd prefer to just change the definition of `FOLDERS` in the first line. I've googled around and tried a few things, but I feel like either I can't find the right incantation to use, or I'm missing a piece of knowledge about how Makefiles work. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that you probably want to use `$<` not `$^`.  Also note you can replace `$(notdir $<)` with `$(<F)`.  That's some amount of simplification.

Comment: Regarding the first suggestion, is there a functional difference between `$<` and `$^` when there is only one prerequisite? And thanks for the second!

Comment: There is no functional difference.  However `$^` is wrong if you only want the first prerequisite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that there's no good reason to use PHONY targets here, since these rules appear to be building files whose names are known beforehand. Targets like `f1/f1.pdf` would be much better.

Unfortunately we can't use a pattern rule when the stem (e.g. `f1`) is *repeated* in a prerequisite. But a ["canned recipe"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) can do the trick:

```
define pdf_template
$(1): $(1)/$(1).md
    cd $$@ && pandoc $$(notdir $$^) -o $$(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,$$(notdir $$^))
endef

$(eval $(call pdf_template,f1))
$(eval $(call pdf_template,f2))
$(eval $(call pdf_template,f3))
```

(Note how you must escape the `$` signs in the template.)

If those `$(eval...)` lines look too repetitive, you can replace them with a loop:

```
$(foreach folder,$(FOLDERS),$(eval $(call pdf_template,$(folder))))
```

**EDIT:** Come to think of it, there's another way. You can't construct a pattern rule that uses the stem more than once:

```
$(FOLDERS): %: %/%.md
    cd $@ && ... this won't work
```

And you can't use the [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) in the prerequisite list, because they aren't yet defined when they're needed:

```
$(FOLDERS): $@/$@.md
    cd $@ && ... this won't work either
```

But you *can* use them there if you use [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), which causes Make to expand the prereq list a second time:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(FOLDERS): $$@/$$@.md
    cd $@ && ... this works
```

Again, note the escaped `$` symbols.

Comment: If you keep the directory as the target, you _do_ need the `.PHONY`.  If you do as you suggest and change the target to `$(1)/$(1).pdf` then you don't need (or want) `.PHONY`.  You also might want to add `$(1): $(1)/$(1).pdf` so you can still run `make f1` etc.  And if you do this, you still need the `.PHONY`.  So, you probably want to keep the `.PHONY` :)

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. TIL about canned recipes, nice solution. I gave you an upvote but apparently my rep is too low for it to show a public score. 
I decided to keep the phonies, because I'm lazy and typing out the whole path is too much work ;)

Comment: @MadScientist: Hey, I didn't say don't keep the `.PHONY`, I said don't keep the PHONY targets. I mean, I know you can't have Phony Targets without the "PHONY", and you shouldn't have "phony" targets that aren't **PHONY** targets, but the *targets* that, that I, that you, I mean that he-- Oh, my head...